# How to disable expanding run button

Tags: vscode-code-runner

[image: screenshot]

Code runner expands run button on click (new behaviour), is there any way to set the default?

(run in terminal enabled)

I just need a single click to run the program. (I want Run Python file in Terminal to be default action)